# How can I serialize/deserialize JSR310 classes using json4s and Jackson?

Tags: scala, jackson, json4s, jsr310

I have a case class:

`case class Stuff(createdOn: Instant)`

and I'm using json4s with Jackson to provide my JSON serialization/deserialization. However, I'm not able to serialize/deserialize `createdOn` properly.

If I was using plain Jackson, https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310 would be great. However, when using json4s, even if I register the JSR310 module using

`org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())`

I'm still unable to get my `Instant` right.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you please describe in detail what kind of error message you get when trying to get your `Instant`?

Comment: I don't get any error, it just tries to serialize it like a `Object` instead of formatting it in ISO Date Format as it should if the `JDK8Module` was working properly.

Comment: can't you use a CustomSerializer for instants?